# How to display two detail grids in jqGrid from a master grid?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I am currently able to open one Master Table A grid with only one detail grid list, either for Table B or C in jqGrid. When I select a row in Master A the related selections are displayed in either B or C.

What I have however been unable to achieve is to have the Master A and the two separate B and C grids displayed at the same time, for a total of three grids.

Is this possible? And if so, can anybody either point me to an example that shows this or explain what I need to do to make this work?

I am currently using the following code in default.php file to load the separate lists, but only the Master and one of the detail show. I can chose which one, but not both at the same time.

```
  <body>
  <div>
      <?php require_once("WI_CA_Cases_grid.php");?>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
      <b>Click and Select a Case above, to see the Sessions and Clients involved in that Case</b>
      <?php include ("WI_CA_Sessions_grid.php");?>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
      <?php include ("WI_CA_Clients_grid.php");?>
  </div>
```

Hope someone has an easy explanation for me.

Thank you in advance,
Adri

Comment: Yes it is possible. Which product do you use? - Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript or Guriddo Suito PHP?

Comment: I do not think that here  is something special. In order to have two sync detail grids you will need just to add the code for the second grid in (detail) after the first one.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Are you saying that rather than using the two separate grid.php files(WI_CA_Sessions_grid.php and WI_CA_Clients_grid.php), I need to have the two grids into only one grid.php file?

Comment: No, it is better to have two separate files.